React Hook Forms - Button (not submit) is causing the whole component to re-render on click
So here is my code,
When ever I click the Add to list button the page is being re rendered several times.
I know it's something to do with react hook forms, because if I move the button outside the form it doesn't do it.
I'm trying to call setBannersDataList but this doesn't work outside the react hook form, only works with the button inside the form.
Any help?
'use client';

import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from '@/components/ui/select';
import { Button } from './ui/button';
import { SubmitHandler, UseFormRegister, UseFormReturn, UseFormSetValue, set, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel } from './ui/form';


export default function Component({ details }: EditorProps) {
  const [bannersDataList, setBannersDataList] = useState<any>([]);
 

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any> = (data) => console.log(data);

  const form = useForm<any>();

  const {
    register,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = form;


  console.log('boo');

  return (
        <Form {...form}>
          <form className="grid w-full items-start gap-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="size"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Sizes</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Select
                          {...field}
                          defaultValue="300x250"
                        >
                          <SelectTrigger id="size" className="items-start [&_[data-description]]:hidden">
                            <SelectValue placeholder="Select a size" />
                          </SelectTrigger>
                          <SelectContent>
                            {details.sizes?.map((size) => (
                              <SelectItem value={size} key={size}>
                                {size}
                              </SelectItem>
                            ))}
                          </SelectContent>
                        </Select>
                      </FormControl>
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
               // click this causes the component to re-render loads of times even
               // boo is consoled logged out like 20 times when I click this button
              }}
            >
              Add banner to list
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Form>
  );
}

What I am expecting is that when I click on Add banner to list button and call setBannersDataList, the component doesn't re render so many times.

The reason maybe is that the button clicking also triggers default behaviour of form to be submitted when the button is clicked. that's why it is not re-rendering the form when you moved the button outside the form.
Another method you can implement is to add a line in the onClick callback(e.preventDefault()), here is the code for button while keeping it inside form,
<Button
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // new line added
    // your further logic
  }}
>
  Add banner to list 
</Button>


thanks @shubham, I made these changes and it calls the setBannersDataList but the page doesn't re-render, but if I change something on the page such as the select component, then everything works. How can I get it to trigger automatically. Seems like under the hood, the code is firing but isn't refreshing the page now.

You've nested a form in a form, which is not valid HTML. I'd start with that.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I had the same issue. The simple solution, if you are planning to have multiple buttons inside a single Form element:

Make sure you only have 1 type="submit" button
Add type="button" to the other buttons inside the form

This will effectively prevent unwanted form submissions and re-renders.

For other people that might be facing the same issue. If you're using shadcn/ui library and you want your button to have a tooltip and accidentally put into TooltipTrigger a button element, than get rid of the button element and every method or property push to the TooltipTrigger, coz it in itself is a Button, or at least has button properties as you can see:
const TooltipTrigger: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<TooltipTriggerProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>

So basically if you had something like this:


  <TooltipTrigger type='button' onClick={openFileInput} className=''>
                <button type='button' onClick={openFileInput} >
            <FaImage className='text-2xl' />
            <input onChange={selectImages} multiple ref={fileInputRef} type='file' className='sm:hidden'/>
              </button>
        </TooltipTrigger>



Change it to:


      <TooltipTrigger type='button' onClick={openFileInput} className='text-primary-color p-2'>
            <FaImage className='text-2xl' />
            <input onChange={selectImages} multiple ref={fileInputRef} type='file' className='sm:hidden'/>
        </TooltipTrigger>




It seems like the issue you're facing is related to the re-rendering of your component triggered by the onClick event of the button inside the form. This behavior is likely to be caused by the interaction between React Hook Form and your component's state updates. One possible solution is to prevent the default behavior of the button's onClick event, which could be causing the form to submit and trigger a re-render. You can achieve this by calling event.preventDefault() inside the onClick handler. Here's how you can modify your button's onClick handler:
<Button
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
    // Your logic here
  }}
>
  Add banner to list
</Button>


thanks @mahdi-mohammad, I made these changes and it calls the setBannersDataList but the page doesn't re-render, but if I change something on the page such as the select component, then everything works. How can I get it to trigger automatically. Seems like under the hood, the code is firing but isn't refreshing the page now.
